# sed to match zero or more number of spaces in a string

Tags: sed, regular-expression, json

```
function getVal {
  sedPattern='s/^.*"keyVal":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
  finalSedPattern=${sedPattern/keyVal/$2}
  echo $(sed $finalSedPattern  <<< $1)
}
```

This is my Json parser written using `sed`. It takes json string, key name and returns the value like,

```
myJson='{"hello":"sk"}'
val=$(getVal $myJson hello)
echo $val
```

prints, `sk`

But sometimes, my json string may or may not contain space as,

```
myJson='{"hello" : "sk"}'
```

In that case, the function fails. I tried with tweaking the above pattern  by adding `[ ]` to match zero or more spaces as,

```
sedPattern='s/^.*"keyVal"[ ]+:"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

It throws error as,

```
unterminated `s' command
```

How can i give non-capturing pattern groups inside sed?

Answer (score 6):

Your `sedPattern` has some issue with quotes. you are trying to match the same quote twice.
Also, + is used for one or more. for 0 or more, use *.
caution: code below is untested, but should get you going.

`sedPattern='s/^.*"keyVal"[ ]*:.*\(".*"\).*$/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

You should quote variable expansions (just one example from your code):

```
sed $finalSedPattern
```

is unquoted and will be split on spaces (when used). You should use:

```
sed "$finalSedPattern"
```

Your function with quotes:

```
function getVal {  
    sedPattern='s/^.*"keyVal":"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/1'
    finalSedPattern="${sedPattern/keyVal/$2}"
    echo "$(sed "$finalSedPattern"  <<< "$1")"
}
```

And with optional spaces:

```
function getVal {
    sedPattern='s/^.*"keyVal"[ ]\{0,\}:[ ]\{0,\}"\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/1'
    finalSedPattern="${sedPattern/keyVal/$2}"
    echo "$(sed "$finalSedPattern"  <<< "$1")"
}
```